# Reading integer wrong from text field

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm trying to change a UILabel depending on which is the highest intValue of 4 textfields. Here is my code, but when I enter and integer it prints totally wrong to the console. For example "1" is printing as 520387200

Here is my code, any idea on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

```
    -(IBAction) upDateCalories{
        NSLog(@"Update Calories has been fired");

         if( [breakfast.text intValue] > [lunch.text intValue] && [dinner.text intValue] && [snacks.text intValue]) {

            MostCalorificMeal.text = @"Breakfast";
            NSLog(@"breakfast is highest");

        }


        else if( [lunch.text intValue]  >     [breakfast.text intValue] && [dinner.text intValue] && [snacks.text intValue])    {

            MostCalorificMeal.text = @"Lunch";
            NSLog(@"Lunch is highest");

        }     


       else if( [dinner.text intValue] >    [breakfast.text intValue] && [lunch.text intValue] && [snacks.text intValue]){

            MostCalorificMeal.text = @"Dinner";
            NSLog(@"Dinner is highest");

        }     

     else   if( [snacks.text intValue] >    [breakfast.text intValue] && [lunch.text intValue] && [dinner.text intValue]) {

            MostCalorificMeal.text = @"Snacks";
            NSLog(@"Snacks is highest");

        } 

        NSLog(@"breakfast %d",breakfast);
        NSLog(@"lunch %d",lunch);
        NSLog(@"dinne %d",dinner);
        NSLog(@"snacks %d",snacks);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The values you are logging are objects of type `UITextField`. You can't use the `%d` format specifier to log `UITextField`.

Change your logs to this:

```
NSLog(@"breakfast %d@",breakfast.text);
NSLog(@"lunch %@",lunch.text);
NSLog(@"dinner %@",dinner.text);
NSLog(@"snacks %@",snacks.text);
```

And your `if` statements are incorrect. You can't use that syntax to compare one value against several other values. You need something like this:

```
if ([breakfast.text intValue] > [lunch.text intValue] && [breakfast.text intValue] > [dinner.text intValue] && [breakfast.text intValue] > [snacks.text intValue]) {
    // breakfast is the greatest
} else if ...
```

It would be even better if you used some variables:

```
int breakfastVal = [breakfast.text intValue];
int lunchVal = [lunch.text intValue];
int dinnerVal = [dinner.text intValue];
int snacksVal = [snacks.text intValue];

if (breakfastVal > lunchVal && breakfastVal > dinnerVal && breakfastVal > snacksVal) {
    // breakfast is the greatest
} else if ...
```

This way you don't keep evaluating the same values over and over.

Comment: Thanks guys, with both of your posts I was able to solve all of my problems. Thanks again!! – user2579356 just now edit